# Progressive matrix of dominoes

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix, dominoes

Here is another unsolved puzzle from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ravensmatrices/comments/18nqiil/anyone_can_solve_this/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1). What is the pattern on the final domino?

[image]

Comment: Should this puzzle have the [tag:knowledge] tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it should be

> a domino with 5 pips on the left and 6 pips on the right

because

> if you view each row of dominoes as a single six-digit number and perform subtraction, you get 524601 - 363245 = 1613**56**.

Comment: PSE is broken this is a brilliant answer imo +1.

Comment: It seems like iq puzzles are really out of fashion these days. A couple of years back this would have had way more upvotes by now.

Comment: @PDT agreed this answer is great. Reddit has a lot of good places for iq test related puzzles where there is a good reception for challenging questions and well thought out responses to them !